# Building C# Wrapper around C++ lib files

Tags: c#, wrapper

I have couple of lib files and I want to use in my project. How to build the C# Wrapper around C++ lib files.

Any weblink or any tutorial you know, please send me.

Thanks in advance.

Harsha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a C++ CLR Class Library project, and then write a C++/CLI class which wraps the functions in your libs.

From C#, you can then add a reference to your class library, and call the class and its methods directly.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the C++ CLR class library.

You can also consume it using DLLImport

```
//c# code
[DllImport(@CPPProjectName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void SendData(string args);
```

Invoke the method in normal way

```
SendData("data123");
```